# Redirect subdomain to another laravel subdomain

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I had a laravel project on a sub-domain and I migrated to another sub-domain.

I want to redirect all requests from old sub-domain to the new one.

For example:

```
https://old.website.com
https://old.website.com/login
https://old.website.com/contact
```

Should become:

```
https://new.website.com
https://new.website.com/login
https://new.website.com/contact
```

I moved all the files to another folder and added `.htaccess` with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the issue is that `public` is added to the url for example:

```
https://old.website.com
```

Becomes:
https://new.website.com/public

So I get 404 not found error.

For the sub-domain I set the document root to point to public folder so no need to add the public directory to the url.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you likely have an internal rewrite to the `/public` subdirectory. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://new.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Test with 302 (temp) redirect first to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution on one of my projects. To redirect requests from old sub-domain to the new one without the public folder in the URL, you could need to modify the .htaccess file. You can try the following code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.website.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.website.com$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ https://new.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect all requests to the new sub-domain while preserving the rest of the URL. This way, you should be able to access the pages at their new URL without encountering a 404 error.